# Heap corruption when trying to read in a file

Tags: c++, cin, heap-corruption

Let me bring you up to speed on what my code is trying to do. I am taking a .txt file and reading it into my program so i can store the data in a DataFrame class in my project. The first read in block of code here does just that and reads in just fine. (the code block dealing with colNames)

```
char** colNames;
int j = 0;
colNames = new char*[c];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { //I am assuming that each name is no more thann 100 characters
    colNames[i] = new char[100];
}
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    cin.get(strg); //read the first character
    j = 0;
    do {
        colNames[i][j++] = strg;
        cin.get(strg);
    } while ((strg != ',') && (strg != '\n'));
    colNames[i][j] = '\0';
    (*firstDF).setColName(i, colNames[i]);
}

char** rowNames;
j = 0;
rowNames = new char*[r];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    rowNames[i] = new char[100];
}

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    cin.get(strg);
    do
    {
        rowNames[i][j++] = strg;
        cin.get(strg);
    } while ((strg != ',') && (strg != '\n'));
    rowNames[i][j] = '\0';
    (*firstDF).setRowName(i, rowNames[i]);
}
```

But when i copy it and paste it below it to redo essentially the same process but for my rows, I get a heap corruption error and my program crashes. I cant figure out why its doing it and what is going on.

If you could help me understand why its doing this when I have two separate arrays that arent conflicting with each other in any way. that would be fantastic. I appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Comment: You have a `j = 0;` for each `colNames` read but not for the `rowNames`.

Comment: This wouldn't have happened if you used `std::string::push_back()` instead of manual array indexing. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate arrays of sizes `c` and `r`, but iterate both arrays through 100 elements. The last loop does not reset `j`.

Replace the first

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
```

Replace the second

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
```

Replace the last loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < r; i++, j = 0)
```

If you are assuming that each name is no more than 100 characters then you should add `j < 99` in `while`-conditions. I used 99 since the 100th char is reserved for `\0`.

Do not forget `delete[]` after each `new []`

Avoid using `new` statement. You are using C++ and lost the great benefits using manual memory management.
Instead of `char**` and `new char*[]` and then `new char` use `std::vector<std::string>>`. More other since you are using fixed size arrays, use `char[100]` on the stack instead of `new char[100]` in the heap.